# Accelerometer on a wheel's rim

Tags: acceleration, home-experiment

If I put a 3-axis accelerometer on a vertical wheel's rim which acceleration is going to give to me?

Will the gravity interfere my results?

Comment: Is this a 3-axis or a single axis accelerometer?

Comment: Do you put it on the center of the wheel, or on the rim?

Comment: Yes, 3-axis. And the accelerometer is on the rim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a point *A* on a rolling wheel and calculate the radial force $N$ needed to keep it affixed, as well as the tangential force $T$. The angle $\theta$ is the orientation of the wheel with $\theta=0$ at the highest point. The derivatives are $\omega$ and $\dot\omega$.

$$ N = m g \cos\theta + m r \dot\omega \sin \theta - m r \omega^2 \\
T = m g \sin \theta -m r \dot\omega \cos\theta - m r \dot\omega $$

So deepending on which axis you are measuring, yes gravity will affect the results. The only time gravity does not affect the results is during free fall, and when the direction of gravity is perpendicular to the direction of measurement.

If you average over exactly one turn then

$$ N_{ave} = - m r \omega^2 \\ T_{ave} = - m r \dot\omega $$